# Optimize an integral using tools from variational calculus.

Tags: optimization, contest-math, variational-analysis

Last week i attended a competition with some friends and there was the following problem:

> Let $f$ be a function with continuous derivative over $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Prove that $$\int_0^1|f(t)-f'(t)|dx\geq\frac{1}{e}$$

A friend of mine solved it by using the auxiliary function $g(t)=e^{-t}f(t)$, taking its derivative and then integrating it.

When i was solving the problem i remember a course in which we used a variational approach to minimizing this kind of integrals that ended up in with the Lagrangian of the integrand. I tried using this method in the problem but could not work the lagrangian out

¿Could there be an approach to this problem using the calculus of variations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.